# Есть ли веб морда для PF?

Tags: freebsd

Есть ли веб морда для PF?

Answer (score 1):

А [PF Web Admin Tool 2](http://code.google.com/p/pfw2/) подходит ?

Comment: Ему для работы веб сервер нужен? А попроще что-нибудь есть?